# Import in body of module; reorder to top import/first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

every time i run `npm run build` on my react app, i get a weird error that ive never seen before, the react app was made with the command `npx create-react-app --template typescript .` and here is the error:

```
src/components/coin/Buy.js
  Line 10:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 12:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 13:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

src/components/coin/Sell.js
  Line 10:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 12:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 13:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

src/components/games/JoinGame.js
  Line 10:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 12:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 13:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 14:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

src/pages/Login.js
  Line 10:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 12:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 13:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 14:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 15:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 16:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

src/pages/Register.js
  Line 10:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 11:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 12:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 13:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 14:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 15:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

i searched everywhere for an answer, i'm talking about discord servers, github, stack overflow, etc. and i cant find a solution. now this may look like a duplicate question, because it roughly is but in the other post on here that i saw the error was that they declared a constant before importing anything, in my case all my imports are at the top, see here (Buy.tsx):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Alert from '../Alert';

const Buy = ({ coin, boughtCoin, coinId, cookie, balances: b }: any) => { // react component
  ....
});
```

and here is what tsc compiled it to (Buy.js):

```js
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
import { jsxs as _jsxs, jsx as _jsx, Fragment as _Fragment } from "react/jsx-runtime";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import Alert from '../Alert';
```

as you can see the imports are going below all that randomness at the top. and its only for a these 4 files out of the 20+ typescript and javascript files i have in my dir.

Comment: These are not "weird errors", they're [linter rules](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/imports-first.md). And it seems you a) configured typescript to output the compiled files in the src directory instead of a separate build directory and b) configured eslint to run on those files, instead of on the sources only.

Comment: i have gone ahead and changed the output to a build file and only ran eslint on ```./src```. the weird errors are still presenting themselves.

Comment: Did you delete the old output files? Surely eslint won't complain about a `src/components/coin/Buy.js` file that doesn't exist. Did the locations of the warnings change?

Comment: the location changed to the build file... and yes they are deleted in the old dir...

Comment: So you *didn't* run eslint only on the `./src` directory then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240959/discussion-between-muty02-and-bergi).